# Can I buy a Delta Air ticket from Amsterdam via Minneapolis to Toronto without a US Visa?

Tags: bookings

Can I buy a Delta Air ticket from Amsterdam via Minneapolis to Toronto without a US Visa?

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question. But it's worth noting that because the US doesn't have air-side transit, all passengers arriving in the US from international destinations other than from airports with [US Preclearance Facilities](https://www.cbp.gov/travel/preclearance), will pass through US Immigration and Customs when they first land in the US. That means that every passenger on the flight must be admissible into the US. If inadmissible, the airline won't allow the passenger to board the US-bound flight.

Comment: Do you mean "buy a ticket" or do you really want to know if the flight can be taken without a visa or other US admissibility?

Comment: Airlines check your visa status (if required) at the airport shortly before boarding, not when you make the ticket purchase.

Comment: Can you buy a ticket? *Yes*. Can you use it? That depends on whether you have the correct documentation. To get an answer you need to at least state your citizenship